# Fluid content fixed sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I must slice a website which needs to be full-width and full-height (no scroll).
Its structure is very easy : the body has a 20px border (inside) a sidebar and a content, where will be a horizontal slider ( see image below ). [image]

My problem is, what do you recommend to me for setting sidebar width ?
Would you recommend to me to use fixed width for sidebar and jquery for calculate the width of the content or is better to use width for sidebar and also for content in percents ? 
If there is a better way let me know.

Note : I develop it in SCSS(CSS3) and HTML5 and it also should be compatible with talbets

Comment: This can be done with pure CSS, no need for jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `%` `width` for your sidebar, but also provide `min-width` and `max-width` values. Something [like this](http://dabblet.com/gist/3965112).

Code for the demo

---

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='sidebar'></div>
<div class='content-wrp'>
    <ul class='content'>
        <li class='slice'></li>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
html, body, .sidebar, .content-wrp, .content, .slice {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body { border: solid 20px lightblue; }
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    min-width: 10em; width: 20%; max-width: 32em;
}
.content-wrp {
    overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 1em; 
}
.content { width: 4000px; }
```

Comment: Max-width isn't supported by IE6

Comment: The question is tagged with HTML5 and CSS3. And my calendar says we're in 2012, not in 2005.

Comment: Even so, cross-browser should be appreciated.

Comment: No, cross-browser only includes IE8+ http://blogs.windows.com/ie/b/ie/archive/2011/12/15/ie-to-start-automatic-upgrades-across-windows-xp-windows-vista-and-windows-7.aspx Requiring IE6 support more than 6 years after IE7 came out is standing in the way of progress and that's something that should never be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common problem - one column needs to have a fixed width and the other needs to be responsive.

This article:

http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-box-model/1-column-fixed-1-column-fluid.html

provides two solutions, one based on absolute positioning and the other on floats.

Comment: Yes it does - try this http://css.flepstudio.org/css-box-model/2_colonne_fissa_fluida_float.html